# Can you add features, modify or extend typescript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to add features to typescript without making a fork? Is it possible to add plugins? An example of such a features would be [optional chaining (elvis operator)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) e.g.

```
const x = {};
console.log(x.y); // throws an error
console.log(x?.y); // console logs undefined
```

As far as I know it is possible to add such a feature to babel ([see](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining)).

Whether this is a good or a bad idea is a different story. All I'm asking is it physically possible and if not then why?

Comment: The [safe navigator operator feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16)  already exists.

Answer (score 2):

No. Babel and TypeScript are two quite different beasts. As far as I know, configuring [tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) is all you can do to change TS compiler behavior.